# Box for multiple lines and automatic width

Tags: boxes

I feel this is rather a dumb question, but I could not find an answer. I'm looking for a `\parbox` without the `width` parameter, i.e. it should be determinded by its content. And the content is multiple lines. Something like:

```
       A
I like B , but who cares?
       C2
```

An `\mbox` or `\makebox` doesn't allow for line breaks, it seems and a `\parbox` wants a `width` parameter. There must be some easy solution for what I want, no?

Comment: Probably `varwidth` (from the package with the same name) is what you're looking for. Or just a `tabular` environment.

Comment: Thanks! The tabular in a simple macro works just as I want. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about a simple `tabular`?

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

I like \begin{tabular}{l}A\\B\\C2\end{tabular} but who cares?
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Maybe with `@{}l!@{}` instead of `l`?

Comment: @egreg yes, that would probably be best :)

Comment: @egreg Thank you for the comment; `@{}l@{}` is just what I needed for text to fit snugly around the tabular.

Answer (score 5):

Another simple solution with the `stackengine` package. The line separator is by default a blank space, but may be changed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}

\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}

I like \Centerstack[l]{A B C2} but who cares?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What fun would have make a table or use a package for this? A funnier method:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
I like \rlap{\raisebox{1em}{A}}\rlap{\raisebox{-1em}{C2}}B, but who cares?
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

In the above example, the width C2 have no effect on the inline text, so the comma is over the number two. If this is a problem, simply do not use `\rlap` for the the longest row of stacked text:

```
I like \rlap{\raisebox{1em}{A}}\rlap{B}\raisebox{-1em}{C2}, but who cares?
```

If rows are multiline  paragraphs, simply enclose it in  a `\parbox`. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
I like \vrule{} 
\rlap{\raisebox{1em}{A}}\rlap{B}\raisebox{-1em}{\tiny\parbox[t]{6cm}{\lipsum[2]}}%
, but who cares?
\end{document}
```